# Django error TypeError at /admin/ 'set' object is not reversible

Tags: python, django

I just learned Django, I'm following the 'Writing your first Django app' from the website. But when I come to the Django Admin part, I got an error.

```
TypeError at /admin/
'set' object is not reversible
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'set' object is not reversible
Exception Location: D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _populate, line 455
Python Executable:  D:\python\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['D:\\python\\projek\\mysite',
 'D:\\python\\python38.zip',
 'D:\\python\\DLLs',
 'D:\\python\\lib',
 'D:\\python',
 'D:\\python\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 1 Feb 2020 08:37:20 +0000
```

I realize that the error comes when I add new path to the urls.py file as the tutorial told.

Here is my urls.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')), <<---- This is the problem
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

here is my polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = {
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
}
```

When I add the polls path the error comes, but when I comment that line the app work.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: post your polls url also

Comment: @bmons i've added the polls/urls.py

Comment: urlpatterns is a list NOT a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your url pattern to

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/detail/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Instead of curly brackets you have to use square brackets and make pattern in such a way that it should not **overlap**

Comment: Oh my god, i don't realize that i use the wrong brackets, thank you so much.